# Adding Style to An asp.net button

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to add styling to my button. It works if I use a normal html button without the `asp:` in front of it, but as soon as I add the `asp:` keyword, it does not work. I must use `asp:Button` in order to write code for the button in the code behind. I've looked at other stackoverflow questions but unfortunately did not provide much help, the answers did not work on my side.

the button

```
<asp:button CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click"></asp:button>
```

CSS

```css
.btn {
    width: 250px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position: relative;
}

.btn::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-top-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    transform: scale(0.1, 1);
}

.btn:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}

.btn::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

.btn:hover::after {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.1, 1);
}
```

**EDIT:**
I have an `asp:Button` on another page where I only use `class="btn"` and that works fine with the styling.

```
<asp:button runat="server" class="btn" onclick="btnLoginLink_Click" Text="Login"></asp:button>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it does not work'? `CssClass` is valid (for an  `asp:button` ), does the issue still occur if you swap the attribute with `class` ? Also could there be a conflict with styling on the page? Try renaming `btn`

Comment: I've written the page in VSCode for the live page feature, please note that everything was names the exact same, now it does work in normal html but as soon as I use it in asp.net the styling does not work. I looked at both ```CssClass``` and ```class``` and yet none work. And it is only for the ```asp:Button``` if I just use ```button``` it works perfectly

Comment: Can you add the ASP.NET & html control side by side, show a screenshot and a snippet of the page source (so we can see thats being rendered)?

Comment: Sure sure, give me a minute

Comment: @Greg the pages https://imgur.com/a/mNqPkfn

Comment: Do you also have a snippet of the raw HTML that has been rendered ?

Comment: Is there something specific you want to see from the rendered html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238935/discussion-between-greg-and-pureware-legends-of-gaming).